# Problem implementing WebView into a Fragment

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi I was developing a Simple App, which consist into a mutiple fragments which contains differents WebView inside.

I can Change this which a Button.

My problem is that I get a NullPointerException when I passed the WebViewClient to my Object WebView.

Here my Code:

MyWebViewClient.class

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
}
```

WebViewFragment.class

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private WebView myWebView;

    public WebViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment WebViewFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static WebViewFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        WebViewFragment fragment = new WebViewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);
        myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        String url = "https://www.elpais.com/index.html";
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        //browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pages/html/search.html");
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }
```

WebViewFragment2.class

```
public class WebViewFragment2 extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private WebView myWebView;

    public WebViewFragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment WebViewFragment2.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static WebViewFragment2 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        WebViewFragment2 fragment = new WebViewFragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /// Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view2, container, false);
        myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView2);

        String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hola DAM</h1>" +
                "<h1>Título 1</h1><h2>Título 2</h2><h3>Título 3</h3>" +
                "<p>Ejemplo de un párrafo en HTML estático. </p>" +
                "</body></html>";
// load static html data on a web view
        myWebView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");




        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }
}
```

And finally where I get the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.pruebafragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String url = "https://elpais.com/";
    Button btnPrimerFragment;
    Button btnSegundoFragment;
    //MyWebViewClient wbClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Creamos el webView
        WebView wb1 = (WebView) findViewById(webView1);
        WebView wb2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

        //wbClient =new MyWebViewClient();
        //TODO: NullPointerException: Objeto WebViewClient es null.
        wb1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wb2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //Habilitamos JavaScript
        WebSettings settings1 = wb1.getSettings();
        WebSettings settings2 = wb2.getSettings();

        configurawb1(wb1, settings1);
        configurawb2(wb2, settings2);

        WebViewFragment wbf1 = new WebViewFragment();
        WebViewFragment2 wbf2 = new WebViewFragment2();

        btnPrimerFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrimerFragment);
        btnSegundoFragment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSegundoFragment);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fTrans = fm.beginTransaction();

        btnPrimerFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fTrans.add(R.id.frameLayout, wbf1);
                fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fTrans.commit();


            }
        });
        btnSegundoFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fTrans.add(R.id.frameLayout, wbf2);
                fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fTrans.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    private void configurawb1(WebView wb1, WebSettings settings) {
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wb1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        settings.setMinimumFontSize(65);
        wb1.loadUrl(url);
    }
    private void configurawb2(WebView wb1, WebSettings settings) {
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wb1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        settings.setMinimumFontSize(65);
        wb1.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

If you know some about and can help, take thanks for advance!

Comment: Please show your R.layout.activity_main,, where it appears you also have two WebViews?, or at least you're trying to get references to them in MainActivity.onCreate

Answer (score 0):

your object myWebView is null from here:

```
myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

check the layout file *activity_main.xml* to make sure you actually have there a WebView with id *webView1*